# How can I write a copy assignment operator to handle references

Tags: c++, vector

I have the following composition:

```
PropertyCollection
{
  private:
    Dataset & dataset;
  public:
    PropertyCollection(Dataset & _dataset) : dataset(_dataset) {}
```

I need to have a `vector<PropertyCollection> properties`.  I need to be able to call `properties.resize(10, PropertyCollection(dataset));`

Unfortunately the vector requires a default constructor `PropertyCollection::PropertyCollection()` to default-initialize its elements.  In other words, it must call `PropertyCollection::PropertyCollection()` when it `resize`s. Thus, I believe that in order to property initialize my vector when I call `resize` I need to implement a default constructor and a copy assignment operator.

```
PropertyCollection
{
  private:
    Dataset & dataset;
  public:
    PropertyCollection() = default;
    PropertyCollection(Dataset & _dataset) : dataset(_dataset) {}
    PropertyCollection & operator=(const PropertyCollection & other)
    {
      dataset = other.dataset
      // error, cannot reassign a reference
```

Unfortunately, my attempt at writing a copy assignment operator failed miserably.  We cannot reassign a reference.  What, then, can I do to get my vector working?

To expand upon my question, is this something that other people have grappled with? (The fact that vector is hard to deal with because it uses a default constructor 100% of the time)

Comment: References can't be reassigned, period. Use a pointer.

Comment: I don't know whether a `std::reference_wrapper` is really what you want, but it exists.

Comment: To expand upon my question, is this something that other people have grappled with?  (The fact that vector is hard to deal with because it uses a default constructor 100% of the time).

Comment: @chris that was so incredibly vague - no malice in my comment, thanks for the chuckle :).

Comment: @chris `std::reference_wrapper` looks right.  Any tips on implementing it?

Comment: @jakeliquorblues, It's very possible to make a vector not use the default constructor in many circumstances, but it does always require the contained objects to be copyable or moveable. I imagine the extent of using `std::reference_wrapper` would be just changing your first code's member to `std::reference_wrapper<DataSet> dataset;`. However, I don't know what kind of semantics you're going for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not use reference members.

If your `PropertyCollection` instance "owns" `Dataset`, then make `Dataset` a normal member of the owning class and be done with it. Your class should look like this:

```
PropertyCollection
{
  private:
    Dataset dataset;

  public:
    // NOTE: single-argument ctors should be made explicit
    // NOTE: and the formal parameter should be const ref
    explicit PropertyCollection(const Dataset& _dataset) : dataset(_dataset) {}
    // ...etc etc, other ctors, ...
};
```

If a `Dataset` instance is *shared* among several containing objects, then use a shared pointer to express the shared ownership: `std::shared_ptr<T>` if you work with a C++11-compliant compiler, or the [Boost smart pointer template](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm) otherwise. I mention this only for the sake of completeness because I suspect you do not have this use case.